# what BitSet.nextClearBit do how it check for false

Tags: java

Can someone explain what actual bitSet.nextClearBit do i try to understand from javadoc but I was not able to get clear picture how it set to false.

Comment: Returns the index of the first bit that is set to {@code false}
     * that occurs on or after the specified starting index. What you dont understand please?

Comment: what are you trying to do? I don't get your question, honestly. Javadoc's description is sufficient

Comment: I was trying to know how the nextClearBit works, if BitSet has value {1,2,4,6,7} why it return 3 when we can bitset.nextClearBit(1) how it work basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In boolean logic, the terms `set` and `clear` have specific meanings. 
`Set` means the value is `1` or `true`
And `Clear` means, the value is `0` or `false`.

A small program to demo nextClearBit in **[Codiva.io compiler ide](https://www.codiva.io/p/2e90ad00-00d1-4f0e-986d-f637568a952d)**. Run and see the output.

**nextClearBit** takes an int parameter that is the index from which to start the search.
If you pass the value k, then if kth bit is 0 or false or not set, out will return k, otherwise check k+1 if it is not set, then k+2 and so on, until an index at which the bit is not set, that is, `clear`.

Comment: Happy to know it helped. A suggestion, consider trying out an example when you see some unfamiliar API, if writing and compiling code is difficult time consuming in text editor or IDE, consider simple online IDEs like https://www.codiva.io or http://ideone.com

Comment: Saw cadiva.io its great to have such a tool thanks for link.